# Walrus Operator: NameError: free variable 'it' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python, scrapy, walrus-operator

I want to create a list using the walrus operator like this:

```
    myvar = tr_list[8].css('td ::text').extract()
    item['myvar'] = [
        it := re.sub(PATTERN, "", i).strip() for i in myvar if len(it) > 0
    ]
```

And I get this error:

```
    it := re.sub(PATTERN, "", i).strip() for i in myvar if len(it) > 0
NameError: free variable 'it' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
```

On the other hand it works when I do it this way:

```
    myvar = tr_list[8].css('td ::text').extract()
    item['myvar'] = [
        re.sub(PATTERN, "", i).strip() for i in myvar if len(re.sub(PATTERN, "", i).strip()) > 0
    ]
```

where:

```
PATTERN = "\r|\t|\n"
```

Can anyone help? I don't know what I am missing here

Comment: It will do `if len(it) > 0` before it does `it := ...`; so you have a catch-22 where the variable can't be defined because it isn't defined yet.

Comment: Thanks @deceze . I think I got it by changing it to `n for i in myvar if len(n := re.sub(PATTERN, "", i).strip()) > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I think I finally solved it by changing it to:

```
    myvar = tr_list[8].css('td ::text').extract()
    item['myvar'] = [
        n for i in myvar if len(n := re.sub(PATTERN, "", i).strip()) > 0
    ]
```